# Angular adding a random number to requests for .js files which I do not want

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express, browser-cache

Excuse me if its a trivial thing... I haven't been able to get around this problem.

I would like all my Js files to be cached (I have set the maxAge as one day, as you can see in the code snippet below). The css and images are getting cached in the browser but not the .js files.

Something somewhere is adding a random number to each js file as a query string parameter which is forcing the browser to not cache, I guess its probably the express thats doing this.

Is there anyway to configure the express correctly so that the random number querystring is not added.

```
var oneDay = 86400000;

app.use(express.compress());

app.use('/assets', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/app/assets/'), { maxAge: oneDay }));
app.use('/app', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/app/'), { maxAge: oneDay }));
```

And here is my browser log showing the random number added to the js file

[image: Browser network log]

Thanks in advance...

Comment: In fact it doesn't really look like a random number, but rather a timestamp. Timestamps like this are used to control the browsers cache. Are you sure there is a new number on every refresh, and not just when updating a js file / a day went by?

Comment: Express doesn't automatically add timestamps to client-side code. How are you generating your HTML?

Comment: @Hless thanks for your response. Its a new number each time I navigate to the page that has reference to the js file. This is showing as HTTP 200 which I expect it to be 304 (or since I have set the definitive age, I am thinking there should be no request from the browser until it expires)...

Comment: @robertklep thanks for the comment. All my html files are static and using Angular I fetch/manipulate the data. Infact the .html/css/images files are perfectly getting cached. Its just the .js files that are not. As you can see in my code snippet above,  using express.static I mapped the static files.

Comment: @Mouli are you using a JS loader like require.js or something similar? Or are the JS files loaded by Angular?

Comment: @robertklep the js files are referenced in html with script tag <script src="app/folder/filename.js"></script>. And no i am not using the requirejs yet.

Comment: @Mouli if you're using those script tags in your HTML, and they are requested from the server with an additional timestamp added to them, it should be client-side code that's rewriting the URL's.

Comment: @robertklep that makes sense. The html that comes from the server doesn't come with the timestamps added to the js files.

Comment: @Mouli perhaps Angular does it, but I haven't experienced anything like that myself (although I've only used Angular 1.0, things might have changed with Angular 1.2)

Comment: @Mouli do you use any JS / resource loader in your page to load all other JS files? I expect that you use some JS loader which appends that parameter (`?_`) in order to *force* a browser in order to download latest version of file and do not use browser cache. BTW, jQuery `ajax` function uses similar technique when `cache` is set to `false`: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Angular uses jQuery (if present). Otherwise it uses jQLite, a stripped-down version of jQuery. When making AJAX calls, jQuery automatically adds the timestamp to the querystring. A hack-ish way to get around this is to call `jQuery.ajaxSetup({cache: false})`. There’s probably a better way that an Angular expert could tell you, so I’ve added the angularjs tag to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all, it seems like the code you posted there is actually node.js (ExpressJS), not AngularJS. The maxAge attribute is related to caching, although as @robertklep points out this is not causing the addition of the timestamp. (see http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.sendfile)?

Second, Angular supports resource caching via the $resource object itself - see this:
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource

Third and more likely - the timestamp shown is identical to how jQuery works with AJAX, as suggested by @Nate in the comments. It may very well be that modifying the $resource configuration / call will resolve this.

Lastly, posting a little more code would be helpful in determining what's wrong.

Comment: How can Express add timestamps to URL's in static HTML files?

Comment: Have not tested it. Only a suggestion. I said "might." Hard to see, the problem is, without enough code to look at (paraphrasing Yoda). But after consideration, I believe @Nate's comment is a more likely possibility - it is likely jQuery or jQlite.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what prompted you to think that code was Angular. It is NodeJs, and until the point where @robertkelp pointed out that it may be Angular - I never had that doubt. Happy to paste in more code, but its a very simple app where the nodejs code looks like the above and the html has <script> tag to include the js files.

Comment: I'm sorry for the title. The original was "NodeJs(Express) adding the timestamp", and apparently modified by Nate to the "Angular..." to get some Angular experts attention. Thanks for your help.